# Vector as an exponent in Julia

Tags: vector, julia

I have very basic question. I am new to Julia and used to code in R a lot. I need to take a scalar to the multiple powers, represented by a vector: 3^[2,3]. I got an error "Method error: no method matching ^...". I tried 3^Array([2,3]), but got the error again. At the same time, 3*[2,3] works as expected. Is there any way to do it in Julia without using for loop?

Comment: It seems I have found an answer: instead of 3^[2,3] I should use [3^(x) for x in 2:3]. But it is still seems weird that exponentiation operation does not work in the same elementwise way as multiplication.

Comment: Or even better: 3.^[2,3].

Comment: I highly recommend you to read this: http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/noteworthy-differences.html#Noteworthy-differences-from-R-1 especially on the usage of `*`.

Answer (score 9):

I think you are looking for the `.` or `broadcast` functions that allow you to apply any other functions elementwise!

`3 .^ [2,3]` or `broadcast(^, 3, [2,3])`

Answer (score 1):

Small edit: you'll need a space after the number to be exponentiated, e.g. `3 .^[2,3]`.